# Mosaic plot/grid plot in black and white for dummies

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, vcd

I have a data set consisting of dummies, which looks like follows:

```
# Example data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(x1 = rbinom(10, 1, 0.3),
                   x2 = rbinom(10, 1, 0.6),
                   x3 = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5))
```

I want to create a mosaic plot/grid plot (actually I am not sure how such a plot should be called), in which each 1-value is displayed in black and each 0-value is displayed in white. There should be no white space or any other color between the displayed lines.

An example of a plot I would like to create could be found in [this paper on page 97](http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.31.2.87):

[image]

I tried several different packages like `ggplot2` or `vcd`, but unfortunately I was not able to produce exactly the same plot. Any help or any hint for a package is highly appreciated!

Comment: @Axeman I think x axis is x1, x2, x3.

Comment: The x-axis are variables 1-10, so if you consider my example data above it would be x1, x2, x3. The y-axis is the row, so in my example above it would be 1:10.

Comment: Perfect, it is so easy when you know how to do it. Thanks a lot Axeman!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `image` function is perhaps the easiest way to display matrices with colors. You need to transpose and reverse it to have the order correct

```
image(t(as.matrix(data[nrow(data):1, ])), col = c(0, 1), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, seq(0, 1, l = ncol(data)), seq_len(ncol(data)))
axis(2, seq(0, 1, l = nrow(data)), seq_len(nrow(data)))
legend(1.1, 0, c(0:1), fill = c(0, 1), xpd = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is using *ggplot*:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) #to convert wide to long format

plotDat <- gather(data, key = "x", value = "Estimate")
plotDat <- cbind(plotDat, y = 1:10)
plotDat$Estimate <- as.factor(plotDat$Estimate)

ggplot(plotDat, aes(x, y, fill = Estimate)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @ zx8754! Nice to have an alternative in ggplot2

Comment: @JoachimSchork no problem, though, it would need a bit more code to replicated output of simple base `image` function.